# Google map leave by time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am currently trying to figure out if there is a way to calculate what is the best time to leave by in order to reach my destination using google maps api.

example: San Francisco -> Menlo Park 
ArrivalTime: 12pm
CurrentTime: 11:00am
Leave by time: 11:30am

Currently [distancematrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) api seems to fit my needs; however, setting the arrival time or departure time does not give a response with when to leave.

So I am wondering, if I am missing something or is there another api within google that can be used.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not implemented in the Google Maps API yet. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker that is tracked in the

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829984

Currently the feature request has 28 stars, however it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task. I would suggest starring a feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.

Hopefully one day Google will implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

In the API, setting arrival time only works for public transit, not fit driving. You could still calculate it by using a guess and check method if it's a desperate need and you're willing to burn additional API calls.